# data structure many-to-many(3way) relationship

Tags: c#, data-structures

Im stuck with this little project in C# but basically my problem is this:
Im trying to create a data structure for exam stats...
So:
one student can have many subjects
and one subject can have many students
the complicated part is that, one subjects can have multiple exams(retakes), so therefore a student will have many results for one subject...
Im kinda lost of how to normalize this. Can anyone suggest? this is my first solution:

```
class StudentRec
{
    string name;
    string candidate_number;
    string student_id;
    List<Subject> modules;
}

class Subject_Record
{
    string subject_code;
    Exam_Record first_attempt;
    Exam_Record second_attempt;
    Exam_Record third_attempt;

}

class Exam_Record
{
   string year;
   int mark;
   char grade;
}
```

however, if I did it this way,each student would have a different instance of the same subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

- Student

  - name etc
- Subject

  - code etc
- Enrolment/Student-Subject (many-to-many)

  - student reference
  - subject reference
  - date of enrolment etc
- Exam (one-to-many from Enrolment)

  - enrolment reference
  - date of exam
  - mark/grade

So a Student enrols in a Subject -> Enrolment.  Then for an Enrolment you can have many Exam(s), one for each sitting to handle retakes.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Mike Q's answer.

```
class Student
{
    string name;
    string candidate_number;
    string student_id;

    // One to many
    List<Enrollment> modules;
}

class Enrollment
{
    Subject subject;

    // One to many
    List<Exam> exams;
}

class Subject
{
    string subject_code;
}

class Exam
{
    int attempt;
    string year;
    int mark;
    char grade;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the subject records to the student, so the student has a list of subjects he is taking and he also has a list of results for current and past subjects he has undertaken. So the code becomes:

```
  class StudentRec
  {
    string name;
    string candidate_number;
    string student_id;
    List<Subject> modules;
    List<Subject_Record> subject_results;
 }

 class Subject_Record
 {
    string subject_code;
    Exam_Record first_attempt;
    Exam_Record second_attempt;
    Exam_Record third_attempt;   
 }

 class Exam_Record
 {
   string year;
   int mark;
   char grade;
 }
```

If you wanted to link from Subject_record and Exam_Record back to Student, you can add the student id to those records.